# return multiple values from a single ternary operator in java

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I have a single condition if that is satisfied then I need to update more than one value accordingly. I'm looking for a ternary operator to do this.

```
int a    = Condition ? 1 : 0;
String b = Condition ? "success" : "error";
```

I need something like this

```
(int a, String b) = Condition ? (1, "success") : (0, "error");
```

I'm not sure if something in java exists like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way as you can't write `(int a, String b) = (1, "success");`, no, you can't do this in Java.

All you can do - if you want them as separate variables - is to use an `if` statement:

```
int a;
String b;
if (condition) {
  a = 1;
  b = "success";
} else {
  a = 0;
  b = "error";
}
```

If you would accept having `a` and `b` as fields in a class (which I'm not going to define here), you could write it as something like:

```
Result r = condition ? Result.create(1, "success") : Result.create(0, "error");
```

You can then unpack `a` and `b` from `r` as required.